# O que são os Evergreen Browsers? Essa filosofia também se aplica a desenvolvimento de sistemas?

Tags: html, html5, navegador-de-internet, cross-browser, metodologia-ágil

Escutei esse termo, **Evergreen Browsers** em uma palestra em inglês sobre a evolução dos navegadores etc., mas não entendi bem o que seria esse conceito.

O que seria um navegador `Evergreen` ou o que é essa filosofia? Ela também se aplica ao desenvolvimento de sistemas? Em um time ágil é possível seguir essa prática?

Teria algo a ver ou tem alguma ligação com **Progressive Enhancement** *(Aprimoramento progressivo)*?

Answer (score 1):

Cara, dei uma estudada pra te ajudar e o que encontrei foi:

O termo "evergreen" refere-se à estratégia de lançamento. Os navegadores Evergreen são atualizados com freqüência em segundo plano, constantemente atualizando sua conformidade com os padrões Web e também adicionando recursos proprietários.

A versão de um navegador perene, como por exemplo o Microsoft Edge,  perdeu sua importância, porque espera-se que um navegador evergreen seja executado na versão mais recente.

Em suma, parece que o ponto de "navegadores evergreen" é a atualização constante. O Chrome, por exemplo, se não me engano, tem um cronograma de atualização pra não ficar obsoleto.


Espero ter te ajudado :D

Answer (score 1):

Outra definição de Navagadores *Evergreen* são na verdade as suas **versões**.

As versões *Evergreen* são as **duas mais recentes** de cada navegador.

No momento em que eu escrevo essa resposta, a versão mais recente do Chrome é a 102. Então as versões Evergreen do Chrome são as **v102** e a **v101**.

Isso é um conceito importante para por exemplo o *Angular*, que mantem as suítes de teste internas especificamente para as versões Evergreen, podendo haver incompatibilidades crescentes com as versões progressivamente mais antigas que estas duas mais recentes.